# Will we get frequent conflicts when using storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib, conflict

I think using storyboard will save us a lot of work sometimes. But when more than one mates working on the same storyboard. Is it possible that conflicts occurs frequently? When using .xib I and my workmates will have conflicts when we are working on the same .xib. So how about the storyboard? BTW:Don't tell me to use more than one storyboard. I think I prefer xib than storyboard if I need to use more than one storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one big storyboard for your app, and several developers on your team will need to make changes in the storyboard, you will probably get conflicts.

If you're using xibs, you can put unrelated views in separate xibs.  Then when developer A needs to change something in view 1, he just changes the xib containing view 1.  And at the same time, if developer B changes something in view 2, he changes the xib containing view 2, which is probably separate from the xib containing view 1.  So you don't get a conflict.

If you're using a storyboard, all the views are in one file.  So developer A changes the storyboard to modify view 1, and at the same time developer B changes the storyboard to modify view 2.  Boom, you get a conflict.

If your team has multiple developers working on the app user interface, you are much more likely to get conflicts if you use storyboards than if you use (carefully-separated) xibs. This is a serious problem with storyboards.

However, you can't create a table view controller with static content in a xib.  You can only do that in a storyboard.  So sometimes it's worthwhile to create a storyboard containing just one table view controller, in a project that uses xibs for everything else.

Comment: So it should be a bad choice to choose storyboard instead of xib for team work? What a pity!